# YouTube Live Stream Captioning Posts dropping lines/words

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

Starting last Friday (9/15/17) we started having problems sending captions to live events on YouTube. It appears that the API has changed.  The heartbeat post started enforcing the time stamp followed by a blank line format, before last week, an empty post worked fine, now an empty post returns a 500 error instead of the UTC time. Also, a much bigger problem - we are experiencing missing words and lines in the caption display. This just started late last week as well.  Looking for some technical support from anyone involved at YouTube with the HTTP Post Captions API. The only documentation I have is from 2013 when we started using the API (ClosedCaptionHTTPPOSTProtocol.pdf), I cannot find any documentation for this API anywhere on YouTube.